# Difference between call-by-value and call-by-name interpreter for the lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, callbyname, call-by-value

In another question, Bob presented the following [interpreter for the untyped lambda calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752112/interpret-parigots-lambda-mu-calculus-in-haskell).

```
data Expr = Var String | Lam String Expr | App Expr Expr

data Value a = V a | F (Value a -> Value a)

interpret :: [(String, Value a)] -> Expr -> Value a
interpret env (Var x) = case lookup x env of
  Nothing -> error "undefined variable"
  Just v -> v
interpret env (Lam x e) = F (\v -> interpret ((x, v):env) e)
interpret env (App e1 e2) = case interpret env e1 of
  V _ -> error "not a function"
  F f -> f (interpret env e2)
```

[Ivan Zakharyaschev remarked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752112/interpret-parigots-lambda-mu-calculus-in-haskell#comment45828142_28752112) that this interpreter is call-by-value due to `F f -> f (interpret env e2)`. **How would the implementation of a call-by-name interpreter be different from the one presented above?**

Plotkin studied [call-by-name and call-by-value strategies](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/cbn_cbv_lambda.pdf) for evaluating the lambda calculus in the 1970s.

Comment: This looks like call by need to me, since Haskell is call by need (modulo pedantry)

Comment: `f $! interpret env e2` would get you call by value.

Comment: @loqui This is definitely not call-by-need or call-by-name. The normal call-by-name Y combinator causes an [infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6715144/414413), suggesting that this is in fact call-by-value and requires a call-by-value [fixed-point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think proper call-by-name is possible with the original data definition. `F (Value a -> Value a)` has `Value a` as argument, so we have no choice but to pass in some already interpreted value, and it'll be call-by-need under Haskell reduction behaviour.

We could modify the data definition:

```
data Value a = V a | F ((() -> Value a) -> Value a)
```

And also have the interpreter return explicit thunks:

```
interpret :: [(String, () -> Value a)] -> Expr -> () -> Value a
interpret env (Var x) = delay (case lookup x env of
  Nothing -> error "undefined variable"
  Just v -> force v)
interpret env (Lam x e) = delay (F (\v -> force (interpret ((x, v):env) e)))
interpret env (App e1 e2) = delay (case force (interpret env e1) of
  V _ -> error "not a function"
  F f -> f (interpret env e2))

force :: (() -> a) -> a
force f = f ()
{-# NOINLINE force #-}

delay :: a -> () -> a
delay a () = a
{-# NOINLINE delay #-}
```

Now, instead of storing a thunk in the environment, we store a [partial application object](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#Partialapplications), and then evaluate it separately at different call sites.

`force` and `delay` are required to prevent GHC from floating out function bodies, [thereby recovering sharing.](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/#memo-off) Alternatively, one could compile with `{-# OPTIONS -fno-full-laziness #-}` and use simple lambdas and applications instead instead of the above machinery.

Comment: Unfortunately, GHC relies on full laziness very heavily to support other transformations. Maybe someone will do something about that some day, but I'm not optimistic.

Answer (score 3):

CBV/CBN are concepts related to the evaluation strategy of the lambda calculus, i.e. related to the choice of redex in lambda term reduction. In an operational-style interpreter which reduces terms representations, you can properly speak of CBV/CBN.

In a denotational-style interpreter like the posted one, I'd speak of eager vs lazy semantics, instead of CBV/CBN. Of course eager corresponds to CBV, and lazy to CBN.

Since Haskell is lazy, the code

```
interpret env (App e1 e2) = case interpret env e1 of
  V _ -> error "not a function"
  F f -> f (interpret env e2)
```

implements a lazy semantics (CBN). (As luqui states, operationally GHC would reduce this in a call-by-need fashion).

To get an eager (CBV) semantics, we can force the argument before the call:

```
interpret env (App e1 e2) = case interpret env e1 of
  V _ -> error "not a function"
  F f -> case interpret env e2 of
         V v -> f v
         F g -> f g
```

This ensures that no unevaluated thunks are fed to a function, unless they are already in the environment. The environment, however, is populated only when evaluating a lambda, which will insert the values `v`,`g` above in the environment. Hence, no thunks will be inserted there.